# Spring MVC multi select listbox value value cannot return to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a multi selected list box in jsp, and the value cannot return to controller. But other fields work fine.

I have tried the options type in the search Form class from List or String[], but still no data return.

Here is the code:
Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void test(@ModelAttribute("searchForm") Search searchForm, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){ 
     List<String> options = (List)searchForm.getOptions();
}
```

Form:

```
Public class Search{
  private List<String> options;

}
```

JSP:

```
<select id="options" name="options" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
    <option value="3">option3</option>
</select>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

In your JSP, make some modifications using spring form tag.

```
<form:form method="post" action="test" modelAttribute="search">
     <form:select multiple="true" path="options">
        <form:options items="${options}"  />
    </form:select>

    <input type="submit" name="addOptions" value="Add Options">
</form:form>
```

I had sample selectbox project on github, I've added multi-select option too. If you take a look you can figure out by yourself: https://github.com/jama707/SpringSelectBoxSample

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I cannot change to use spring form tag since my jsp is actually very complex. However, my problem got solved by using jquery to change the selected option to have selected="selected" during the submit, then the value can be passed.